# Verses not ragged right

Tags: formatting, verse

When I use the `verse` package, a single verse will not be ragged right if it is broken at the end of the line. How do I change it to being ragged right?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
    This verse is very long and therefore will be typeset across two lines.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a MWE illustrating the problem?

Comment: I can not notice that behavior. Please add a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to add that it happens when you have two columns. The questions has been edited.

Comment: But, by default (whether using `article` or `scrartcl`), the `verse` environment doesn't typeset the text in raggedright fashion. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you describe the desired output in more detail?

Comment: I misunderstood something. The problem is neither `scrartcl` nor the two columns. What I want to achieve is that a line with a line break is ragged-right, just like all the other lines. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, (whether using `article` or `scrartcl`), the `verse` environment doesn't typeset the text in ragged-right fashion.

If you want to use ragged-right text in the `verse` environment, you can use [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and add

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\raggedright}
```

to the preamble. A complete example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{In the beginning}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{And objects at rest tended to remain at rest}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Then God created Newton, \\
And objects at rest tended to remain at rest, \\
And objects in motion tended to remain in motion, \\
And energy was conserved
and momentum was conserved
and matter was conserved \\
And God saw that it was conservative. \\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Just for comparison, the output obtained commenting out the `\AtBeginEnvironment` line in my example code above:

[image]

Perhaps better to use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\RaggedRight}
```

after loading the [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package.