# Patching \raggedright to solution environment does not work in exam class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam, etoolbox

Consider the MWE given below.

I am trying to patch the
solution environment with `\raggedright`. But it does not seem to work.
However, when an explicit `\raggedright` is issued at the start of the
same environment, it works.

---

```
\documentclass{exam}

\printanswers 


\unframedsolutions
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\raggedright}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 



\begin{questions} 

  \question Question

  \begin{solution}

    Text without explicit \verb@\raggedright@.

    \lipsum[2]

  \end{solution}

  \begin{solution}

    Text with explicit \verb@\raggedright@.

    \raggedright

    \lipsum[2]

  \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: @erik I get confused by your comment, care to explain?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. At the end of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223009/24974) it's suggested to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\RaggedRight}` with the `ragged2e` package. You may need to adjust the right margin, but it seems to work.

Comment: @erik So far as my knowledge goes, `\RaggedRight` is not too strict about making the right ragged and allows hyphenations in some cases. And it does not work in the scenario under consideration, I tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal TheSolution environment explicitly resets `\lineskip` and `\rightskip` to 0pt and so cancels the `\raggedright`. The command must be issued later to have an effect:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\printanswers


\unframedsolutions
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\TheSolution{\raggedright}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}



\begin{questions}

  \question Question

  \begin{solution}

    Text without explicit \verb@\raggedright@.

    \lipsum[2]

  \end{solution}

  \begin{solution}

    Text with explicit \verb@\raggedright@.

    \raggedright

    \lipsum[2]

  \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]